# Webform updates CCK field, doesn't update in node edit

Tags: views, entities, caching, webforms

I have a CCK field used to track the number of volunteers needed for a specific position. Once someone signs up to volunteer for that position, the number needed is decreased by one.

The issue is that when I go to edit the original node, the # of volunteers needed is not updated with the new number from the database. I checked the database and I can see that the correct values are being written. They aren't being loaded into the node edit form.

It appears to be a caching issue since when I clear my cache the problem is corrected. Is there a way to fix this apart from turning off caching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out: The CCK field was being rewritten by a cached value instead of a value directly from the database. I told the form to query the database directly, and then it began working correctly.